# Web Audio API and WebRTC

Tags: audio-streaming, webrtc, web-audio-api, peer

Is it possible to getUserMedia...
take the stream and process it with Web Audio API to run it through some filters and then send the processed audio to a peer using WebRTC?

I have been scouring the web for such examples. I found plenty that use Web Audio API after receiving a peer's stream but none processing the audio before sending it to a peer. Also no definitive statements that says it is, or is not, possible.

Comment: If you can process the audio coming from another peer, why do you need to process it before sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out http://simpl.info/webrtcwebaudio.  That sample generates a sound and passes it to a peer; you should be able to get a source from getUserMedia in the normal way (a la http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html) and hook it into Web Audio.